# Spring Boot The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I am trying to query a local SQL Server using the following application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://somesqlservername;databaseName=somedbanme
spring.datasource.username=someusername
spring.datasource.password=somepass
```

And the following code to access the db with jdbc:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @GetMapping(value="/User")
    public User getUser(@RequestParam BigInteger id) {
        String sql = "SOME SQL QUERY";
        User user = (User) jdbcTemplate.query(sql, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class));
        return user;
    }
}
```

The following error occurs when i invoke the service:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
> establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
> Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target".
> ClientConnectionId:8f7627f2-78cf-4479-89fe-9eba6f7be4a5

Comment: SQL Server, by default, is installed with a self-signed certificate. Have you either added that certificate to your Java key store or added `trustServerCertificate=true` to your JDBC connection URL? Ref: [Connecting with encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption)

Comment: I have just tried trustServerCertificate=true and it worked but this is not a secure solution. How can i export SQL server's self-signed certificate?

Comment: If you have access to the SQL Server itself then via SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for (instance name). Instead of importing a new certificate view the existing one and export it to a file.

Comment: There is no certificate to view, the view button is disabled.